# one to many relationship in entity framewrok 4.1 code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mapping, entity-relationship, code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I am initializing the entities like this:

```
    TasksListDB db = new TasksListDB();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var tasks1 = new List<Task>()
        {
            new Task { Id=1, Name = "Task 1", Difficulty = 1, DateCreated = DateTime.Parse("1/12/2011") , IsDone= true },
            new Task { Id=2, Name = "Task 2", Difficulty = 2, DateCreated = DateTime.Parse("11/2/2011") , IsDone = false}               
        };

        var tasks2 = new List<Task>()
        {
             new Task { Id=3, Name = "Task 3", Difficulty = 3, DateCreated = DateTime.Parse("11/2/2011") , IsDone = false},
            new Task { Id=4, Name = "Task 4", Difficulty = 5, DateCreated = DateTime.Parse("1/2/2010") , IsDone= true }
        };

        tasks1.ForEach(t => db.Tasks.Add(t));
        tasks2.ForEach(t => db.Tasks.Add(t));

        var Persons = new List<Person> { 
     new Person { Id= 1 , Age= 10, EmailAddress= "asif_hameed_37@hotmail.com", FirstName= "Asif", LastName="Hameed" },
     new Person { Id= 2 , Age= 10, EmailAddress= "asif_hameed_37@hotmail.com", FirstName= "Asif", LastName="Hameed"  },
     new Person { Id= 3 , Age= 10, EmailAddress= "asif_hameed_37@hotmail.com", FirstName= "Asif", LastName="Hameed"  },
     new Person { Id= 4 , Age= 10, EmailAddress= "asif_hameed_37@hotmail.com", FirstName= "Asif", LastName="Hameed"  }};

        Persons.ForEach(p => db.Persons.Add(p));

        return View(db.Tasks);
    }
```

my db context looks like this:

```
public class TasksListDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }   
}
```

I want to assign tasks to persons how can I do this ?

My model looks like this :

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }        
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Range(1,5,ErrorMessage="Difficulty must be between 1 and 5")]
    public int Difficulty { get; set; }
    public bool IsDone { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

When I run my mvc application, Person and Task tables are created but juntion table PersonTask not created.

[EDIT]

```
I am assigning tasks like this in initializer class:

   var t1 = new Task { Id = 1, Name = "Urgent Task", DateCreated = DateTime.Now, Difficulty = 2, IsDone = true };
            var t2 = new Task { Id = 2, Name = "Business Task", DateCreated = DateTime.Now, Difficulty = 1, IsDone = true };
            var t3 = new Task { Id = 3, Name = "Home Task", DateCreated = DateTime.Now, Difficulty = 2, IsDone = false };

 context.Tasks.Add(t1);
            context.Tasks.Add(t2);
            context.Tasks.Add(t3);

    var Persons = new List<Person> { 
         new Person { Id= 1 , Age= 40, EmailAddress= "asif_hameed_37@hotmail.com", FirstName= "Asif", LastName="Hameed", Tasks= new List<Task> { t1,t2 }},
         new Person { Id= 2 , Age= 30, EmailAddress= "asif_hameed_37@hotmail.com", FirstName= "Asif", LastName="Hameed" , Tasks= new List<Task> { t1}  },
         new Person { Id= 3 , Age= 29, EmailAddress= "asif_hameed_37@hotmail.com", FirstName= "Asif", LastName="Hameed" , Tasks= new List<Task> { t3,t2 } },
         new Person { Id= 4 , Age= 35, EmailAddress= "asif_hameed_37@hotmail.com", FirstName= "Asif", LastName="Hameed" , Tasks= new List<Task> { t1,t3 } }};

 context.Persons.Add(Persons[0]);
            context.Persons.Add(Persons[1]);
            context.Persons.Add(Persons[2]);
            context.Persons.Add(Persons[3]);

            context.SaveChanges();

but when i see the task table in sql server, it looks like this:

Id  Name          DateCreated          Difficulty   IsDone  Person_Id
1   Urgent Task 2011-04-24 19:32:03.990 2   1   4
2   Business Task   2011-04-24 19:32:03.990 1   1   3
3   Home Task   2011-04-24 19:32:03.990 2   0   4
```

I assume that person table should have tasks not the task table should have person Id

```
Please suggest solution.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Junction table will not be created because you have defined one-to-many relation not many-to-many. The `Task` entity in your model can be assigned only to single `Person` not to many persons.

If you want to assing `Task` to `Person` simply run:

```
person.Tasks.Add(task);
```

Comment: @Ladislav: Very good point. thanks. I have updated question. I assume that person table should have task id but I am getting person Id in task. Can you please suggest me what is wrong in my code ?

Comment: Sure you get the PersonId in the Task because your Task has single related Person - task is on the many end of the relation whre FK is defined.

Comment: @Ladislave: But task table is not showing the tasks assigned to person 2 and person 3

Comment: Because your code initialization is incorrect. If you are using one-to-many relation you can't assign single task to multiple persons. Each task can be assigned only to single person. Either change your initializatin or change the `Task` entity to have `ICollection<Person> Persons` instead of `Person Person`

Comment: @Ladisalv: I want that one person can do multiple tasks. what I need to make in initialization/model classes ?

Comment: But do you also want one task to be made by multiple persons because that is exactly what you are doing now.

Comment: No. I just want one task for one person. but one person can do multiple tasks.

Comment: So change your initialization. Your current persons initialization assigns for example t1 to p1, p2 and p3. It can't be done in one-to-many relation. t1 can be assigned only to single person.